# How to convert IList to iEnumerable to honour Interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using an API where I'm implementing an interface that has a method returning an `IEnumerable`.

I'm building the collection in my implementation as a `List`, because I need the `.Add()` method.

Can I then convert this to IEnumerable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `List<T>` implements both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, if you just need it as a return value of a method, you can just return it, e.g:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>{" data"};
    return myList; //works
}
```

what you get on the other side, when you call the method, will be an `IEnumerable<T>` reference that points to a `List<T>` object.

That means that the user can use the result wherever he can use an `IEnumerable<T>`, but also that a simple cast can expose the inner `List<T>` thus allowing modifications of the data. e.g:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = GetData();
Console.Write(result.First()); // " data";

List<string> resultAsList = (result as List<string>);
resultAsList.Insert(0, "other data");

Console.Write(result.First()); // "other data";
```

If you want the result not to be changed, you can use the `.AsReadOnly` method, to return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` that is still an `IEnumerable<T>`, like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>{" data"};
    return myList.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: +1 for `AsReadOnly()`.

Comment: The user shouldn't be casting to a List<T> because that's not what the api exposed.  It would cause brittle code.  If the end user should need IList functionality, then the api should return an IList.

Comment: Casting an `IEnumerable` to a modifiable data structure is by itself extremely brittle code :)

Answer (score 7):

As [Sweko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18329580/632337) mentioned you can simply return list but in case you don't want the list to be modified from outside, you can call [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) on your list to expose `IEnumerable` outside.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
{
   List<string> yourList = new List<string>();
   return yourlist.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really serve any purpose in this case if the method is returning type `IEnumerable<string>` anyway.

Comment: @Rohit Not really. Since `AsEnumerable` only changes the type of the reference (and that is already done by the return statement), a simple `(result as List<T>).Add(...)` will work around that.

Comment: @Sweko - Yeah you are right. I completely overlook that.